# FreeBSD установка shared library

Tags: linux, freebsd, phantomjs

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь поднять phantomjs на FreeBSD. После мануальной установки его 32 битной версии, совместимой с linux в соответствии с гайдом изложенным здесь [установка фантома](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778513/how-can-i-setup-run-phantomjs-on-ubuntu) и запуском совместимости бинарников линукса на freebsd в соответствии с гайдом [запуск совместимости](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/linuxemu-lbc-install.html), команда `phantom -v` возвращает ошибку :

> phantomjs: error while loading shared libraries: libfontconfig.so.1:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Оф документация говорит, что нужно выполнить `$ sudo pkg install phantomjs` для установки необходимых зависимостей, но эта команда ругается на отсутствие данного пакета в репозиторие. Как можно решить проблему установки libfontconfig.so.1 библилотеки в freebsd? Спасибо за любой ответ!

Comment: Используемые версии ПО не уточните? Можете ошибку дословно показать при выполнении  `sudo pkg install phantomjs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации к фантому говорят, что если используются готовые бинарники с сайта, то некоторые зависимости надо разруливать вручную. Чтобы решить проблему с отсутствующим `libfontconfig.so` надо установить [fontconfig](http://www.freshports.org/x11-fonts/fontconfig/):

```
pkg install fontconfig
```

Либо из портов собрать:

```
cd /usr/ports/x11-fonts/fontconfig/
make install clean
```

Но, насколько я помню, Phantomjs есть в [портах](http://www.freshports.org/lang/phantomjs/). Можете попробовать установить из портов:

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/phantomjs/
make install clean
```